# How to operate on all columns with datamash?

Tags: shell, text-processing

Suppose I have the following data file:

```
111 222 333
444 555 666
777 888 999
```

I'm able to calculate the sum per column with GNU Datamash like this:

```
cat foo | datamash -t\  sum 1 sum 2 sum 3
1332 1665 1998
```

**How would I do this with datamash if I didn't know the number of columns in my data file?**

I'm asking because for example `cut` supports end of range symbols like `-` for its field selector.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see an option to specify unknown range in [datamash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/manual/datamash.html#Column-Ranges)

Try this `perl` one-liner

```
$ perl -lane '$s[$_]+=$F[$_] for 0..$#F; END{print join " ", @s}' ip.txt
1332 1665 1998
```

- `-a` option will auto split input line on whitespaces, results are saved in `@F` array
- `for 0..$#F` to loop over the array, `$#F` gives index of last element
- `$s[$_]+=$F[$_]` save the sum in `@s` array, by default initial value will be `0` in numeric context. `$_` will have the index value for each iteration
- `END{print join " ", @s}` after processing all input lines, print contents of `@s` array with space as separator

Answer (score 1):

```
cols=$( awk '{print NF; exit}' foo); cat foo | datamash -t\  sum 1-$cols
```

or

```
cat foo | datamash -t\  sum 1-$( awk '{print NF; exit}' foo)
```

`datamash` has a feature to specify column ranges, so calculate the number of columns and use that result as part of the range spec. In my example solution, I used `awk` to check only the first line of the file and exit, but you could use anything else that suits your fancy. `datamash` itself has a `-check` function whose output includes the number of columns, but in a format that would still need to be parsed for the specific number that's of interest to you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about `datamash`, but here is an `awk` solution:

```
$ awk '{ for( col=1; col<=NF; col++ ) { totals[col]+=$col } } END { for( col=0; col<length(totals); col++ ) {printf "%s ", totals[col]}; printf "\n" } ' input
1332 1665 1998
```

To make that `awk` script more readable:

```
{      // execute on all records
  for( col=1; col<=NF; col++ ) { 
    totals[col]+=$col 
  }; 
} 
END {  // execute after all records processed
  for( col=0; col<length(totals); col++ ) {
    printf "%s ", totals[col]
  }; 
  printf "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `datamash` and `bash`:

```
n=($(datamash -W check < foo)); datamash -W sum 1-${n[2]} < foo
```

Output:

```
1332    1665    1998
```

---

How it works:

1. `datamash -W check < foo` outputs the string *"3 lines, 3 fields"*.
2. `n=($(datamash -W check < foo))` loads that string into an array `$n`.  We want the number of fields, which would be `${n[2]}`.
3. `datamash -W sum 1-${n[2]} < foo` does the rest.

---

This can also be done with a *POSIX* shell, using a complex `printf` formatting string instead of an array, but it's gnarlier:

```
datamash -W sum 1-$(printf '%0.0s%0.0s%s%0.0s' $(datamash -W check < foo)) < foo
```

It can also be done with shell tools:

```
datamash -W sum 1-$(head -1 foo | wc -w) < foo
```

Comment: The first two methods were suggested by [*user1404316*'s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/425935/165517).